# Ubuntu 17.10 UEFI with raid

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, uefi, raid

I have two 3TB hard drives i want to use for my server.
Im not experienced at all regarding file systems and raid.

What i did was to install my disk as following

Sda 3TB

- sda1 512 MB raid
- sda2 64 GB raid
- sda3 2.9 TB raid

Sdb 3TB

- sdb1 512 MB raid
- sdb2 64 GB raid
- sdb3 2.9 TB raid

Raid 1 md0 was used as EFI partition with sda1/sdb1

Raid 1 md1 was used as swap area with sda2/sdb2

Raid 1 md2 was used as ext4 mounted at / with sda3/sdb3

Now the install seemed to work just fine but when i boot nothing happens and i just have a black screen and obviously i made something but dont know how to fix it.

Is it my partitions that is wrong and why wont it start?

(sidenote: Im quite noob on this and followed guides online)

Comment: It might be that grub was only installed on the second disk, with the view of the BIOS which might be `/dev/sda` in Linux. If possible you could check if you can swap the order of the HDD in BIOS and try to boot again. If not, you have to boot from a LIVE media and install grub on both disks manually.

Comment: It is my understanding that the EFI partition cannot be RAID:ed.